# how to search for a node in a xml file to see it exist

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml, xmlnode

I'm trying to take in an xml file. The fields are always the same but sometimes not included.

How would I search for "Name" in vb ?

```
<product>
  <Name>
    <FirstName> John </FirstName>
    <LastName> Doe </LastName>
  </Name>
  <Age> 24 </Age>
  <DOB> 4/5/1990 </DOB>
</product>
```

I tried the code below and got a compilation Error 
  BC30456: 'Contains' is not a member of System.XML.Linq.XElement

```
dim doc as XDocument
if doc.Root.Element("product").Contains("Name") Then
   doc.Root.Element("product").Elements("Name").Remove()
end if
```

Comment: See related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14516559/797393)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to test if the element exists is to simply access it and then check if it is `Nothing`, like this:

```vb
If doc.Element("product").Element("Name") IsNot Nothing Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Notice that I used `doc.Element("product")` rather than `doc.Root.Element("product")` since, in your example XML, `product` *is* the root element.  However, using the `Element` property like that is dangerous because it will throw an exception if the parent element doesn't exist.  In other words, if `doc.Element("product")` returns `Nothing`, you can't then turn around and access `Nothing.Element("Name")`.  So, to correct that, you'd have to do something like this:

```vb
If (doc.Element("product") IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (doc.Element("product").Element("Name") IsNot Nothing) Then
    ' ...
End If
```

But that get's ugly pretty fast.  The easier way is to use the `.<>` syntax to access the elements, like this:

```vb
If doc.<product>.<Name>.FirstOrDefault IsNot Nothing Then
    ' ...
End If
```

That will return `Nothing` if either `product` or `Name` does not exist.  It will not throw an exception if either or both of them were to be missing.  If you did want it to throw an exception, you could still use the `.<>` syntax, but just call `First` rather than `FirstOrDefault`.

Of course, I could point out that all of this would be a bit easier, cleaner, and more flexible if you were to use XPath (the industry standard) rather than Microsoft's proprietary LINQ-to-XML technology, but that would just be petty.  Ok, well, I guess it slipped out against my better judgement, so, as long as I've already said it, I might as well give an example:

```vb
If doc.XPathSelectElement("/product/Name") IsNot Nothing Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Comment: Thanks had to change everything to .<> and it worked!