# How do I remove empty tags from xml file using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have created a program in C# which adds and deletes data in an XML file.
Adding new data works totally fine, however on deleting the data, data gets deleted but empty tags still remain in the xml file.
How do I remove them? please help

The code is as follows:

```
private void deleteall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // delete single record button
    {
        XmlDocument xdata = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode xnode = xdata.SelectSingleNode("Information/Database");
        xdata.Load("C:\\Users\\son14344\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\project.xml");
        XmlNodeList oNodeList;
        oNodeList = xdata.SelectNodes("Information/Database");
        string s;
        s = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
        try
        {
            foreach (XmlElement Oelement in oNodeList)
            {
                if (Oelement.SelectSingleNode("Database_Name").InnerText == s)
                {
                    //Oelement.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Oelement);
                    Oelement.RemoveAll();
                }

                xdata.Save("C:\\Users\\son14344\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\project.xml");

                //}
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your sample Xml

Comment: This might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509188/remove-empty-blanks-elements-in-collection-of-xml-nodes

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Information>
  <Database>
    <S.NO.>1</S.NO.>
    <Database_Name>2</Database_Name>
    <Project_Name>w1</Project_Name>
    <Status>Active</Status>
  </Database>
  <Database>
  </Database>`

This is what I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 Oelement.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Oelement);
```

instead of

```
Oelement.RemoveAll();
```

Comment: That Helped. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture the node that meets your `condition`.

Inside your `if` condition

```
  XmlNode node = Oelement.SelectSingleNode("Database_Name");
  XmlNode parent = node.ParentNode;
  // remove the child node
  parent.RemoveChild(node);
```