# Deserializing empty element into nullable DataTable column

Tags: c#

I am importing xml into a DataTable with nullable columns.  When an element is empty I would expect it to import with null value in the row, but instead I get an error "Input string was not in a correct format."  In the example below the code will create a DataTable with two columns - id is not nullable, moneyValue is nullable.  It prints out the xsd to the Console window - I noticed the attribute 'nillable='true'' is not in there - might that be it?

The Xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="simpleTable" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="simpleTable">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="moneyValue" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("simpleTable");
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)) { AllowDBNull = false };
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn("moneyValue", typeof(double)) { AllowDBNull = true };
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            dt.WriteXmlSchema(sw);
            sw.Flush();

            // emit the schema
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["id"] = 1;
            dr["moneyValue"] = 100;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            // Some xml with two sample rows- the first one will work, the second will not
            string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<DocumentElement>
    <simpleTable>
        <id>2</id>
        <moneyValue>200</moneyValue>
    </simpleTable>
    <simpleTable>
        <id>3</id>
        <moneyValue/>
    </simpleTable>
</DocumentElement>";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            dt.ReadXml(reader);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
<moneyValue/>
```

is not null but empty 
you have to remove that element ... I know this is a trivail solution

```
@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<DocumentElement>
<simpleTable>
    <id>2</id>
    <moneyValue>200</moneyValue>
</simpleTable>
<simpleTable>
    <id>3</id>
</simpleTable>
</DocumentElement>"
```

If you have no control on the XML and you have to handle empty element like

```
 <moneyValue/>
```

you have to switch the type of your column from double to string.
However if you want to have double in that column you can follow this tricky approach: add a third column and populate it with an expression based on the moneyValue in the following way:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("simpleTable");
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)) { AllowDBNull =     false };
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("moneyValue", typeof(string)) { AllowDBNull = true };
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("moneyValueDouble", typeof(double)) { AllowDBNull = true };
dc.Expression = "IIF(moneyValue = '', null, moneyValue)";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
dt.WriteXmlSchema(sw);
sw.Flush();

// emit the schema
Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["id"] = 1;
dr["moneyValue"] = 100;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

// Some xml with two sample rows- the first one will work, the second will not
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<DocumentElement>
<simpleTable>
    <id>3</id>
    <moneyValue/>
   </simpleTable>
</DocumentElement>";
TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
dt.ReadXml(reader);

// not necessary just to have your old datatable
dt.Columns["moneyValueDouble"].Expression = null;
dt.Columns.Remove("moneyValue");
dt.Columns["moneyValueDouble"].ColumnName = "moneyValue";


Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I thought empty element was the same as null.  Creative solution - I decided to just remove any empty elements and rely on defaults or nullability.  Found a great post with a one-liner to remove them all - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509188/remove-empty-blanks-elements-in-collection-of-xml-nodes