# Is there a way to determine which element is causing a deserializing error in .net

Tags: .net, xslt, error-handling

I am importing data into our program.  I have a style sheet that transforms the incoming data to match our entity framework.  I am getting an error when de-serializing the transformed data into our entity framework.  The data in one or more fields is not in the correct format, either an empty Boolean or character data trying to go into a numeric field.  The entity is quite large and it is difficult to track down the specific field.

I would like to know if there is a reference in the exception object that I can use to help track down the field in question.

Here is the error message and stack trace:

```
There is an error in the XML document.

System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToInt32(String s)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderCrashEntity.Read28_CrashNamesEntity(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderCrashEntity.Read29_CrashEntity(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderCrashEntity.Read30_CrashEntity()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
   at XMLUtility.DeserializeObject(String XML, Type ObjectType) in XMLUtility.cs:line 155
   at DirectoryFramework.ImportData() in DirectoryFramework.cs:line 344
```

Comment: It's usually a hunt for the offending line(s) - assuming you're not doing it record by record but attempting to deserialize al the records at once, try to find an offender by looking at half the set, if it's successful, I look in the other half, and keep dividing by two until I find it.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say something like that.  I tried something drastic, I replaced all occurrences of  >< with >-9< and the file processed, except I need to find which of the 98 replacements was the culprit.  That's why I was hoping to be able to find the exact field somewhere in the exception object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the bad actors.  I used a for loop because I know how many empty elements I had, but you can use a while loop instead and go until EOF.

```
string myXML = outputXml;

int startIndex = 1;
int endIndex = 0;
int insertAt = 0;
string fldLIst = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 98; i++)
{
    insertAt = myXML.IndexOf("></", startIndex) + 1;
    startIndex = insertAt + 2;
    endIndex = myXML.IndexOf(">", startIndex);
    string myElement = myXML.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
    myXML = myXML.Insert(insertAt, "-9" );
    try
    {
        importedEntity = XMLUtility.DeserializeObject(myXML, entType);
        fldLIst += myElement + "\r\n";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myElement);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("---------\r\n" + fldLIst);  // The first element here is the one that caused the problem.
```

Once I knew which element was bad, I modified the style sheet to check for an empty string and return 0 if it was empty.  BTW, there may be several empty elements that are causing the issue and you will have to repeat this process until all elements are handled.

Comment: The above code helped me find the bad actors.  However, i still had to handle them.  My initial fix was to check if the element had a value and if not, then set it to 0.  However, because there might be other elements that would be empty in another data set, this method is very tedious.  Since I am using c# to process the files, I decided upon this solution.  [Remove empty/blanks elements in collection of XML nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509188/remove-empty-blanks-elements-in-collection-of-xml-nodes).